# Issue on makefile using mingw32 and SDL2 (undefined SDL_main ... again)

Tags: c++, makefile, sdl-2

I'm struggling a bit with this announcing error a lot of people get but I didn't manage to solve it looking at others makefiles. 
I will first explain what I aim and what I'm doing.

1. I'm creating a lib, called MyLib that uses SDL2 and OpenGL;
2. All references to SDL2 are there except the main function;
3. This lib is using makefile as well with mingw and return the *.a file.
4. I create a dummy exe app that contains the main function and links to MyLib by calling the Starting point object.
5. When trying to link the Dummy exe I'm getting the following error.

> g++ -c ../../src/main.cpp ../../src/DummyGame.cpp -Wall -std=c++11
>   -DMINGW32 -DUSE_STD -DUSE_SDL
>       -DUSE_SDL_IMAGE -DUSE_OPENGL -DOPENGL32  -I../../src -I../../include -I../../../../libs/include -I..
>       /../../../MyLib/src  -L../../../../MyLib/lib -L../../../../libs/lib/mingw32/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2
>       main -lSDL2 -mwindows -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -lopengl32 -lMyLib
>       g++  -Wall -std=c++11 -DMINGW32 -DUSE_STD -DUSE_SDL -DUSE_SDL_IMAGE -DUSE_OPENGL -DOPENGL32  -I../..
>       /src -I../../include -I../../../../libs/include -I../../../../MyLib/src  -L../../../../MyLib/lib
>        -L../../../../libs/lib/mingw32/lib -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -l
>       opengl32 -lMyLib  -o Dummy.mingw32.exe
>       ../../../../libs/lib/mingw32/lib/libSDL2main.a(SDL_windows_main.o): In
>   function `console_main':
>       /Users/slouken/release/SDL/SDL2-2.0.3-source/foo-x86/../src/main/windows/SDL_windows_main.c:140:
>   und
>       efined reference to`SDL_main'
>       collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
>       Makefile.mingw:26: recipe for target 'Dummy.mingw32.exe' failed
>       mingw32-make.exe: [Dummy.mingw32.exe] Error 1
>       --
>       xcopy /Y Dummy.mingw32.exe "../../bin"
>       File not found - Dummy.mingw32.exe
>       0 File(s) copied
>       Makefile.mingw:34: recipe for target 'install' failed
>       mingw32-make.exe:  [install] Error 4
>       --

This is how the main.cpp file look like:

```
#include "DummyGame.h"

using namespace Dummy;

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" 
#endif
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    DummyGame *game = new DummyGame("Dummy", 720, 480);
    game->run(); 

    return 0;
}
```

DummyGame.h includes MyLib headers that will include SDL2 headers.

I am using the correct 32 bits version of SDL2 from folder "i686-w64-mingw32"

This is my actual makefile:

```
CP = xcopy /Y
RM = del /F

TARGET = Dummy.mingw32.exe

PROJDIR = ../..
BASEDIR = $(PROJDIR)/../..
SRCDIR = $(PROJDIR)/src
INSTALLDIR = $(PROJDIR)/bin

INCLUDE = -I$(SRCDIR) -I$(PROJDIR)/include -I$(BASEDIR)/libs/include -I$(BASEDIR)/MyLib/src 

LIBSPATH = -L$(BASEDIR)/MyLib/lib -L$(BASEDIR)/libs/lib/mingw32/lib

LIBSFLAG = -lmingw32 -lSDL2main -lSDL2 -mwindows -lSDL2_image -lSDL2_ttf -lopengl32 -lHikeGDK
LDFLAGS = $(INCLUDE) $(LIBSPATH) $(LIBSFLAG) 
CXXFLAGS = -Wall -std=c++11 -DMINGW32 -DUSE_STD -DUSE_SDL -DUSE_SDL_IMAGE -DUSE_OPENGL -DOPENGL32 
LIBS = $(CXXFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)

MODULES = $(wildcard $(SRCDIR)/*.cpp)
OBJS = $(wildcard *.o)

all: $(TARGET)

$(TARGET): $(MODULES)
    $(CXX) -c $(MODULES) $(LIBS)
    $(CXX) $(OBJS) $(LIBS) -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJS)
    $(RM) $(TARGET)

install: 
    $(CP) $(TARGET) "$(INSTALLDIR)"
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you tried re-order linked libraries? I don't remember the correct order from my head, but it matters (for gcc-family compilers at least). Other thing to check: is `DummyGame.h` including `SDL.h`? If not, that's the problem - it contains SDL_main macro. In best case, `main.cpp` should include `SDL.h` directly.

Comment: I did indeed try different orders on linked libs with no success. Yes, the DummyGame.h includes the MyLib.h file that will include SDL.h. I've for sanity check to also include the SDL.h directly in main with no luck.

Comment: Ah, maybe I see the error - in the second g++ call, you are linking your libraries together, but there are no *.o objects. However, I don't know makefiles, so I don't know how to fix that... (But probably `OBJS = $(wildcard *.o)` looks in wrong directory - just a guess...)

Comment: Definitely got an issue in that place. I'm gonna investigate and get back to you if found something. Thanks ;)